# Is there any way to distingush a macintosh or macOS file type in Windows C#?

Tags: c#, macos, file

My C# project have to dintinguish whether a file about to read is a Mac file, which run over macOS.

There is a C# project running over Windows 2008 or newer. I would like to know whether a file about to read is a Mac file running over Mac operating system.

I want to know whether such a code is possible

```
    string fileType = fileTypeChecker(anonymousFile);
    if(fileType=="mac")
    {
        // do something.
    }
```

Can they be distinguished by file extensions? or any type of file signature?

Comment: What do you mean "running over Mac operating system"? Are you accessing them via network share? If not, and you just want to take an arbitrary file and determine which OS it originates on then, for the most part, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: why? more context please.

Comment: I think the problem with this question is the premise that files have a "type" that has an association with the OS, and the goal is to find it. This is not correct, unless searching for certain specific file types that are proprietary to Apple and so are likely to only originate on Macs. But this is not a property *of the file* that can be discovered.

Comment: I am a security solution programmer. I have mainly been handling with windows PE files. But this time I have to deal with mac files too. Most of times, my SW will run in an isolated environment where no internet connection is available. Like John said, I take an arbitrary file and determine whether it is a Mac file or not. The only way I can think of is to use the extension "dmg" at the moment.

Comment: _"I am a security solution programmer"_ - please [edit] your question to explain your _goal_ instead of your job title. First, you need to **properly** define _"a Mac file running over Mac operating system"_. Because for example a JPEG file can be opened on any OS that has the appropriate viewer software. You mention "dmg", which is a Mac-specific ["Disk Image" file](https://fileinfo.com/extension/dmg) used for software installation. You should know about "magic numbers" to recognize file formats. If you search the web for that, you'll find [`0x6B6F6C79`](http://newosxbook.com/DMG.html).

Answer (score 1):

MacOS uses the Mach-O binary executable format.

You need to look for the signatures of a Mach-O binary, as described here: [How to read Mach-O header from object file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669766/how-to-read-mach-o-header-from-object-file)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/konrad-kruczynski/elfsharp
is the opensource I would like to use to achieve this goal.
Do you think making use of the code snippet below help suceed my task?
I think it is feasible enough.

```
public void ShouldOpenMachO()

    {

        var fileName = Utilities.GetBinary("simple-mach-o");

        ELFSharp.MachO.MachO machO;

        Assert.AreEqual(MachOResult.OK, MachOReader.TryLoad(fileName, out machO));

    }
```

Comment: Looks solid. It depends on your use case though,for a standard linker generated Mach-O should work. If you use it against some crazy hand written executables (like malware) it might not suffice.

Answer (score -2):

From my understanding after reading your question is you want to check the file whether this file is for Mac or Windows. you can do this by :

```
string fileName = "hamza.DMG";
string mimeType = System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName);
```

it will return the MIME mapping for the specified file name and you can differentiate easily on the basis of this mappings. for Further information you can check this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mimemapping?view=netframework-4.8).

> Note : For .NET Framework >= 4.5

Comment: That tells you that a JPEG file is an image, but but whether it's on a Mac.

Comment: I used this code to check on a certain dmg file. It only tells that this file is in octet/stream.

Comment: @HwangInChan : you can differentiate mac file or windows files on the basis of this.

Comment: _"you can differentiate mac file or windows files on the basis of this"_ - no, you can't, because you don't even know what the OP wants, exactly. If I rename a `.exe` to `.dmg`, this code will still return `application/octet-stream` and not tell whether the file is meant for MacOS or for Windows.